# On a round if everyone has called or folded, could the person after the last to call, raise and make everyone have to call again?

Tags: texas-hold-em

If every one on the round has called, can the person left of the last to call, raise and make everyone call that new bet?

Comment: Can depend on the game, in limit stud, typically there is a max number of raises allowed, often 3/4, check with your casinos house rules to be sure. As long as it is not that situation, yes the last player raising will make everyone have to act again with all their options available to them.

Comment: Hey @Brodie, would you be able to clarify your language here, reading Jonast92's answer makes me believe I've misunderstood your question. Has the person left of the last to call already acted? If so then Jonast92 is correct and I'd like to upvote a correct answer, but if that person has yet to act then it's incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Since the person to the left of the last to call has already taken his turn and everyone has called, he won't get another chance. Hence he won't get a chance again in that particular round, thus being unable to raise.

Answer (score 0):

> "could the person after the last to call, raise and make everyone have
>   to call again?"

In the tagged game, Texas-hold-em, no. The person last to call completes the action, forcing the next street to arrive.

There is one exception to this. That's in games where a straddle has been made. The straddle is *usually* only allowed in cash games and takes place before players have received their cards pre-flop.

A straddle is a blind raise that enables the straddler to effectively buy the big blind, i.e. he gets to put in a blind raise before he sees the cards. If the action doesn't change as it gets to him he has the option to check or raise again. The UTG player is usually the straddler but player in later positions can straddle too, that's referred to as a sleeper straddle.

[See more on Straddle and sleeper bets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betting_in_poker#Straddle_and_sleeper_bets).